# how to remove category from database

Tags: categories, database

is there a way to remove the category from the database?

I just moving my old wordpress blog (that has the category in url), to new domain (without category).

I change everything except the category. Even i don't know where it is stored in database :(

### Update

**Problem is resolved, I added the answer below so that it will help to others.**

Comment: are you asking to remove category from url?

Comment: yes, but from the database. I want to complete remove the category

Comment: From url use "no category base" plugin.i do not know how to remove from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done through the following query:

```
delete from `wp_terms` where `term_id` in ( SELECT `term_id`
    FROM `wp_term_taxonomy`
    WHERE `taxonomy` = 'category' ) and `term_id` not like 1
```

This query deleted all the category except the default. Hope this helps to the others.